# Meteor Collection.find use variable as field in dynamic mongo query

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to use a variable as the field specifier in a Collection.find query but tit just ignores it

```
    var qry = "{\"" + field_name + "\":" + field_value + "}"
    console.log(qry)//  {"customer_active":true}
    Customers.find(qry).map(function(customer){// doesn't find anything
        console.log(customer)
        var groups = customer.customer_group_id.push(a._id)

        Customers.update({$set: {customer_group_id: groups}})
    })
```

How can I build a dynamic query

Answer (score 8):

`qry` needs to be an object, not a string.  So build it like this instead:

```
var qry = {};
qry[field_name] = field_value;
```

Comment: Works fine when I try it. Maybe you have a typo?

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the query in a `JSON.parse` did the trick

```
    var qry = "{\"" + field_name + "\":" + field_value + "}"
    console.log(JSON.parse(qry))
    Customers.find(JSON.parse(qry)).map(function(customer){
        console.log(customer)
        var groups = customer.customer_group_id.push(a._id)

        Customers.update({$set: {customer_group_id: groups}})
    })
```

Comment: You are thinking too much like SQL where you had to piece together a string. Try to understand what @JohnnyHK is saying. You need a JavaScript object not a string. You don't have to build the string and then convert the entire thing. You can incrementally build the JavaScript Object as JohnnyHK is showing you.